# Oracle Designer ошибка ORA-00604

Tags: oracle

Знаю, что во всех продуктах Oracle проблема с русским языком. Невозможно создать соединение с базой пока не настроишь языки.

В SQL Developer я решил эту проблему добавив в файл sqldeveloper.conf строку AddVMOption -Duser.region=US, в Jdeveloper 10g - добавив в файл jdev.conf строки AddVMOption -Duser.region=US и AddVMOption -Duser.language=en

Но вот с Oracle Designer видимо дела обстоят иначе и куда добавить строчки с указанием языков и региона я найти не могу. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Если это всё под *nix, то вы всегда можете сменить локаль в терминале и запускать приложение через него:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: А в Windows?

Comment: Боюсь под Windows можно только для всей системы указать локаль.. а это слишком уж большая жертва :)

Comment: Придется жертвовать русской локалью)

Comment: Ну или как аьтернатива: раскопать как же запускается этот Oracle Designer.. может придётся писать какой-нибудь батник.. вот в него тогда и сможете протолкнуть опцию для JVM

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашел такое: в реестре изменил параметр `HKLM/SOFTWARE/ORACLE/DevSuiteHome/NLS_LANG` = `RUSSIAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251` вместо `RUSSIAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251`.

Причем Designer не зависит от Java и создается такое впечатление, что основательно он не менялся с 2000 года.